# if else imageChange

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

Help Please. Everytime when I touch my UIButton, my label should increase existing number (1,2,3,4...) if my UIImageView.image = image1.png and I press at that time my UIButton, my label should decrease -10. Decreasing and Increasing works, but if I deacrease for example from 34 to 24, next time when i press to increase, it increase from 34 not from existing 24.

Here is my code:

```
if (UIImageView.image == [UIImage imageNamed:@"image1.png"]) {
        NSString *dataMinus = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",scoreIncrease - 10];
        [self.label setText:dataMinus];
    }

    else {

        NSString *dataToSend = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",scoreIncrease++];

        [self.label setText:dataToSend];

      }
```

Help to fix that, please.

Comment: please put your question title relevant about Your question see your question is if else image-change but in details you dont wanna chage your image you just change score

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (UIImageView.image == [UIImage imageNamed:@"image1.png"]) {
      scoreIncrease=scoreIncrease-10;
      NSString *dataMinus = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",scoreIncrease];
      [self.label setText:dataMinus];
}
else {
      NSString *dataToSend = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",scoreIncrease++];   
     [self.label setText:dataToSend];
}
```

try this may help U.

Answer (score 2):

Do like following:

```
if (UIImageView.image == [UIImage imageNamed:@"image1.png"]) {
    scoreIncrease = scoreIncrease - 10;   // Store the new value
    NSString *dataMinus = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", scoreIncrease];
    [self.label setText:dataMinus];
} 
else {
    NSString *dataToSend = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",scoreIncrease++];
    [self.label setText:dataToSend];
}
```

For else condition, `scoreIncrease++` leads to `scoreIncrease = scoreIncrease + 1` so the new value is stored in `scoreIncrease` variable and you don't need that extra statement that is used in `if` statement for storing the new value in `scoreIncrease`

Answer (score 1):

The `++` operator will cause it to print the score then increase the variable by 1, as intended. In your first case, however, you're not changing the value of the variable at all - you're simply telling it to print whatever the value is, minus 10. You need another line to actually subtract 10 to modify the variable.